# Rotational equilibrium of a moving block on a rough surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Let's say a block is moving on a rough ground with a velocity v and it is not rotating. I understand that about the centre of mass (C)[image: x], for rotational equilibrium, the torque produced due to friction is balanced by the torque produced by the normal hence the block doesn't rotate.
However My doubt is that since the block is in rotational equilibrium,torque about any axis must be zero. But let's consider a point vertically below the centre of mass on the surface (P) . Since both friction and force of gravity pass through this point the only torque produced is by the normal which is unbalanced thus the body will rotate. What am I doing wrong here?